# What is the complexity of the algorithm without body in for loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
}
```

There is nothing in the body of the loop, but I still think the time complexity will be `O(n)`. Is this true?

Comment: Modern compilers are very good at making optimisations, which consist in replacing code by a more efficient code that has the same result. Here, your code has the same result as not doing anything (or maybe doing `int i = n` directly). If the compiler does that, then the complexity will be O(1). But if the compiler doesn't optimise anything and the loop is really executed, then it's O(n); for instance, incrementation `i++` and comparison `i < n` will be executed `n` times each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your perspective is practical (how fast an actual program will execute), it depends on the compiler and/or runtime system. For instance, a Java compiler will most likely discard this code completely, since logically it doesn't do anything, and it will take zero time. If the compiler doesn't do any optimization, or if it follows a strict contract that says code must be executed even if it has no effect, the time is linear. If the code is executed by an interpreter, without compilation (although your `int` hints that it's a compiled language), it likewise depends on the optimization capability of the interpreter, but it's pretty common that interpreters don't do much optimization and therefore would take linear time.

If your perspective is theoretical, i.e., an algorithm theory assignment, it's not generally defined. It depends on weather the machine model takes possible optimization into account or not.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

As long as this loop is executed (and not e.g. optimized away by the compiler), it is indeed *O(n)*. This is because a loop iteration has some overhead, such as performing the `i++` operation.

Answer (score 3):

That's indeed **true** (with the additional note that the loop is executed, as @Berthur pointed out, so assuming that the compiler does not optimise).  
 Even though the body is empty, you are iterating from `i = 1` to `i = n`. The `for-loop` brings the *linear time complexity*  `O(n)` (**note** that the *space complexity* is `O(1)`, assuming that the `for-loop` you've specified is the only piece of code in your program (so that there are no arrays, maps, etc))